# Autocomplete TextBox on Tab

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I have a WPF TextBox in which I want to allow autocompleting user names by pressing the tab key. The usernames are saved in a list of strings.

Is there a better way than handling the KeyDown/Up/etc events on the TextBox? This seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

you can use the following:

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/WPFAutoCompleteBox/ - **recommended**!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26535/WPF-Autocomplete-Textbox-Control

http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/

Comment: These are overkill for my purpose, I don't need selection, just insert the first matching one. Then if tab is pressed again pick the second match.

Comment: You could loop through the suggestions and focus the next item when you press tab.